# how to make a multiple type users in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I am Building an app for a Charity and I need to make a system with different forms for six different user types. the six types are : patients(with the ability to work or not), founders & managers, regular users, volunteers, Financial & work sponsors. 
patients form has : name, the date of injury, injury percentage, age, gender and some other stuff
other users have common and unique fields like patients for themselves. for now I just want to make the forms and add users from the admin page. should I make six individual forms and inherit from user creation form? if so, how to separate them in the admin page? Can I use one authentication for all of them? I am so confused! could you please help me to make a multiple user sign up forms! I have no idea about the code!!! thanks for the responses

Answer (score 0):

this article may help you [How to Implement Multiple User Types with Django](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)
.
Override user Model by adding some boolean fields(is_regular, is_volunteer..)
and add a model for each of them( that enhirits from User)

Comment: I have read this article but the fact is my users don't have different roles or abilities. they just have different information in their form

Comment: so, you need different models, and add a form and view for each model